# flexiprovider conflicts with bouncycastle when retrieving keys from string

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bouncycastle

I have been using a solution, provided in bellow, to encrypt/decrypt using Flexiprovider for a while. The solution works on galaxy s5 and s6. However, in s9 it does not work because it conflicts with BouncyCastle.
The code that works in s5 and s6:

```
 KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECIES", "FlexiEC");
 CurveParams ecParams = new CurveRegistry.BrainpoolP512r1();
 kpg.initialize(ecParams, new SecureRandom());
 KeyPair keyPair = kpg.generateKeyPair();
 PublicKey pubKey = keyPair.getPublic();
 PrivateKey privKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
 String STRpubKey = Base64.encodeToString(pubKey.getEncoded(), 
 Base64.DEFAULT);
 byte[] decodedPublicKey = Base64.decode(STRpubKey, Base64.DEFAULT);
 X509EncodedKeySpec X509spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(decodedPublicKey);
 KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECIES","FlexiEC");
 PublicKey pubkey = keyFactory.generatePublic(X509spec);
```

The above code gives the following error in s9:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.android.org.bouncycastle.math.ec.ECCurve com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.x9.X9ECParameters.getCurve()' on a null object reference
```

The exception happens here:

```
 PublicKey pubkey = keyFactory.generatePublic(X509spec);
```

Comment: What line is throwing the exception?

Comment: Also, it appears Flexiprovider hasn't been updated since 2014 and the website appears to be gone. That's a sign it's time to get rid of your dependence on it.

Comment: @JamesKPolk The last line is resulting in an exception. The question is updated. You're right. I plan to use SC instead of it. However, I'd like to know how to prevent such conflict for the sake of learning.

Comment: OK, I'll see if I can reproduce this on an emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is caused by the lack of support for that Brainpool curve in the Android-supplied "BC" provider. One fix is to remove the Android-supplied BC provider and install your own copy of BC provider that does support these curves. For example, I added a jar dependency on the latest bouncycastle jar `bcprov-jdk15on-161.jar` to my Android Studio project and added the following lines of code prior to executing your example code:

```java
Security.removeProvider("BC");
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
Security.addProvider(new FlexiECProvider());
```

And the code ran without throwing an exception. You might also consider using a less obscure curve, like `secp256r1`.